# Meaning of ボケに被せて小銭を落とす

Tags: grammar, meaning

I was reading something and I came across the following lines, however the bolded part of the third line had me confused as to what they are saying.

> - 清少納言、いわく
> - 春って明け方やばくない？　と言っているのだが
> - 本来、春の良さとは、**入学してくる後輩がいきってボケたときそのボケに被せて小銭を落とす**のが良いと思っている
> - ほどほどにしてやれよ
> - しかもどうやって歌で詠むんだよ、それ

This seems to be a set up for the joke that comes up later where one of the people listening to them makes a fool out of them　and then they drop some money on the floor:

> - おい、まだボケてねぇよ
> - お前は存在自体がボケだからな
> - 存在するだけでチャリンチャリン落とすとか、正気かよ

Based on this and my understanding of the bolded line above, I think it does mean to drop coins/change when they ボケ. However I am still a bit confused as to well why one would do this (is it a reference to something I am missing?)

Comment: Could you share several sentences right after the bolded sentence? I'm almost certain there is no 元ネタ for this, but I still have trouble understanding the true intention of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not a reference to some well-known episode. It's just his own creative way of describing the "beauty" of spring. Spring is the season when a new school year begins in Japan, and he somehow likes observing clumsy new students.

Answer (score 0):

"ボケに被せる" is a behavior like, when someone tells stupid/pointless thing (ボケ) intentionally (to wait/expect someone is pointing out that it is silly (ツッコミ)) another one tells some more stupid/pointless thing (another ボケ) based on the former stupid thing to make audiences laughing more, since that response would be unexpected (or, very very expected.)

"小銭を落とす" means originally just "paying some coins." If someone says "小銭を落とす" in the shop, he/she is saying he/she would buy something for service that shop provides. Not really he/she drops the coin but pass it to the shops cash register drawer or shopmaster's pocket.

So, "ボケに被せて小銭を落とす" would mean (though I don't know the original context so I cannot know the truth, but), "credit someone that he/she is funny by putting another ボケ comment onto his/her original ボケ talk."

"存在自体がボケ" should mean he/she is funny by just his/her standing there.